# Jenkins: Trigger multiple jobs of another project in parallel and wait

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Scenario is, `Job A's` build have to trigger 100's of parallel paramaterized builds in `Job B` and wait for the return status - `Success` or `Failed` or `Aborted`

```
JOB A 
 |------> JOB B
            - build 1
            - build 2
            -  .....
            - build 100
```

I'm aware of the following plugins can help in a way, but is there any out of box solution or script to wait for the return values of 100's of build status at tandem and then mark the status of the parent Job.

1. Multijob Plugin
2. Multi-Configuration Project
3. Paramterized Trigger
   Plugin

Builds of Job B vary in time, from ~5 mins to ~15 mins.

Comment: What types of jobs are `Job A`and `Job B` (freestyle, pipeline (declarative or scripted))?

Comment: `Job B` is pipeline job(declarative) & `job A` is freestyle

Comment: Ok. Does the `Job A` need to be freestyle job? Would it be ok for your use case to change  the `Job A` to a pipeline job?

Comment: Unfortunately its used across multiple teams, so no.. But would like to hear your thoughts :) 
Freestyle job doesn't support this scenario ?

Comment: Your use case can be easily solved with pipelines. I'm not sure if it is solvable with Freestyle job. Have a look at a plugin for converting freestyle jobs to pipelines.

Comment: Say in case I go with pipelines, how should it be approached

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237172/discussion-between-melkjot-and-voltas).